# Jquery Data table issue when giving length change true

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I call my function for the first time the jquery functions is working properly, but if I call the same function once again without refrshing the page the data table functions are not working.

If I change the length to false it is working perfectly.

```
table = $('#contenttableTemplate').DataTable({
  "retrieve": true,
  "paging": true,
  "responsive": true,
  "fixedHeader": true,
  "lengthChange": true,
  "lengthMenu": [
    [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
    [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
  ],
  "pageLength": 5,
  "order": [
    [5, "desc"]
  ],
  "columnDefs": [{
    "orderable": false,
    "targets": 0
  }],
  "deferRender": true,
  "scrollX": true,
});
```

Comment: "change the length to false". Which value do you mean? "lengthMenu"? And what does "not working" mean? You get an error in the console, or some unexpected behaviour. Please describe your problem more concisely.

Comment: yes, I I change lengthMenu to False this code is working perfectly even if I call the function once again.

Comment: I'm not getting any error but the jquery datatable properties like paging,deferRender are not working

Comment: Sorry lengthChange to false not lengthMenu

Comment: In IE it shows "Object doesn't support this action" while calling the function second time without reloading the whole page